# Switching from static to viewmodel paradigm causes properties to disappear from the combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I'm sure there's a very logical explanation to the misbehavior (and I'm the most likely cause of that). Due to ignorance, I'm uncertain how to resolve it, though. Here's what transpires.

When I bound to a static resource as follow, the property *Name* automatically got displayed (it's begin served by the overridden *ToString* implementation).

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Static local:MainWindow.AllOptions}"/>
```

Then, I try to rewrite the code to the MVVM pattern so I've changed that to this.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AllOptions}"/>
```

Trying to set the *Path* explicitly doesn't work (nothing changes, the program executes well but shows nothing in the list. (A hint is that I've done something wrong because intellisense only suggests *AllOptions* and not *Name* as an alternative for *Path*.)

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AllOptions, Path=Name}"/>
```

So the switch to the view model causes the **text** of the property *Name* to disappear. I can see the number of elements served (and their contents) to be correct when breaking in the constructor for the viewmodel, which looks like this.

```
class Presenter
{
  private IEnumerable<Stuff> _allOptions;
  public IEnumerable<Stuff> AllOptions 
    => _allOptions.Where(element => true);

  public Presenter()
  {
    _allOptions = DataAccessor.GetStuff();
  }
}
```

I've connected the viewmodel to the view like so.

```
<Window.DataContext>
  <local:Presenter/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

What might I have missed?!

## Edit

I just realized that the list bound to the component is **empty**. The binding doesn't occur. I was tricked by the outfolded combo box but when I empty the list, it seems to have a default number of lines it shows independently of the number of added elements! So, the problem is that my binding didn't manage to bind.

In [a blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msgulfcommunity/archive/2013/03/13/understanding_2d00_the_2d00_basics_2d00_of_2d00_mvvm_2d00_design_2d00_pattern.aspx) I see that the bloggers view model implements *BindableBase*. I have no such class according to the intellisense. Is *INotify...* a corresponding thingy?

Comment: Did you remove `static` keywords?

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa Yes (I've tested both versions). No change... (I also corrected the question so your comment might look weirdish.    :)

Comment: You seem confused about the `Binding.Path`... in the following `"{Binding AllOptions}"`, `AllOptions` *is* the `Binding.Path` value... it's the path to the `AllOptions` property. the `Name Path` that you're talking about relates to the individual items in the collection and you should specify that in the [`ComboBox.DisplayMemberPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath(v=vs.110).aspx) property instead... try this: `<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AllOptions}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />`.

Comment: And your Presenter has to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: @Sheridan Thanks for the clarification. I **was** confused on that point. Sadly, it's still not working - I'm experiencing the same misbehavior. More suggestions?

Comment: @user2250152 Why do I need it? I've added it as suggested (didn't resolve the issue though) but I don't see the need for notifying. Do I need to add some attribute somewhere as well?

Comment: @KonradViltersten, I can't see the rest of your code, but if you use the code example in my comment in another project, you'll see that it does what you want... you must have something else getting in the way.

Comment: The model view is all there is at the moment. I think it's more a matter of something **missing** and not **being in the way**. What about the *BindableBase* in my edit? And how do I trouble-shoot it? Any suggestion would be appreciated. Does the intellisense suggest a property name available for you when you type in *DisplayMemberPath=* or do you need to manually add it too? How do I test that I've bound properly?

Comment: You have two ways to define what your items look like. One is to use `ToString` as you did before... just use `return Name;` in there to display just the `Name` of each item. The other way is to provide a `DataTemplate` for your data type. See the [Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN to help with that.

Comment: @Sheridan I think you **have** resolved the issue I had **but** it's not apparent because there's **another** problem hiding it. When I add a list of strings to the view model, I get to bind to it in a new combo box (intellisense works) but during run-time, there's nothing there. My controls don't bind to the view model! I think that's the problem. I'll ask it in another question. Meanwhile - post your comment as a reply, mate.

Comment: Please read something about MVVM, it will save you a lot of time.

Comment: @user2250152 Actually, I've been reading up on MVVM quite a lot. Surprisingly, that's part of the problem, because much of what's written is based on not-fully-correct beliefs and refers to what's **usually** done. As an example: I've seen the suggestion on *INotify...* (made by you and many others), which is incorrect. That's wasn't the problem at all. But many actually believe that's a must-have (instead of good-to-have), which makes their feed-back generic and misleading (despite the best intentions). I think we all behoove of reading but also critical thinking.   :)

Comment: @Sheridan Please post your comment as a reply. You can add that the problem might be (which it was in this case) with the view model's instantiation while initializing (binding went baaad as seen in the output window in VS). Also, it's probably good to emphasize that *INotify...* interface needs not to be implemented (since it seems to be a common misconception amongst less experienced developers).